# PHP: Find and remove duplicate multidimensional array elements based on custom condition

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, duplicates

Here is my array:

```
$productsArray = [
    '0' => [
        'id' => 1,
        'code' => 1000,
        'in_promo' => 1,
    ],
    '1' => [
        'id' => 2,
        'code' => 1000,
        'in_promo' => 3,
    ],
];
```

I need to check if there are elements with the same `'code'` and `'in_promo' => 1` and `3` and to remove the element with `'in_promo' => 1` in favour of the element with `'in_promo' => 3`. How could this be done with PHP array functions? 
 Thanks in advance.

Comment: From the php.net documentation: "Note that array_unique() is not intended to work on multi dimensional arrays." I also need to apply a custom condition.

Comment: Can you post an expected output along with extra input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$productsArray = [
    '0' => [
        'id' => 1,
        'code' => 1000,
        'in_promo' => 1,
    ],
    '1' => [
        'id' => 2,
        'code' => 1000,
        'in_promo' => 3,
    ],
    '10' => [
        'id' => 3,
        'code' => 1000,
        'in_promo' => 2,
    ],
    '11' => [
        'id' => 4,
        'code' => 1001,
        'in_promo' => 3,
    ],
];

$hasPromoNeedle = array_filter($productsArray, function (array $array)
{
    return in_array($array['in_promo'], [1, 3]);
});

print_r(array_filter($hasPromoNeedle, function (array $array1, $k1) use ($hasPromoNeedle) {

    foreach ($hasPromoNeedle as $k2 => $array2)
    {
        if ($array1['code'] == $array2['code'] and $k1 != $k2)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH ));
```